# How to post data into my React application?

Tags: reactjs, post, postman, mern

I have an issue with my react, I'm working on a MERN template but I can't make my post to work, and I want to be able to add a new blog on my site. When I add a new blog, I seem to get it in my console.log. (the title and the description) but not on my app, I believe it's something with my fetch.

this is my **app.js** file

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Router} from "@reach/router";
import Blogs from "./Blogs";
import Blog from "./Blog"; 

const API_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API;

function App() {
  const [blog, setBlogs] = useState([]);
  const [postCount, setPostCount] = useState(0);


  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const url = `${API_URL}/blogs`;
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      setBlogs(data);
    }
    getData();
  }, [postCount]); 

  function getBlog(id) {
    const blogObject = blog.find(data => data._id === id);
    return blogObject;
  }


  //callback så min addBlog ved hvor den skal hente data fra
  async function addBlog(title, description, date) {
    console.log("title", title);
    console.log("Description" , description);

    const newBlog = {
      title: title,
      description: description,
      date: date
    }   

    const url = `${API_URL}/blogs`;
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },
      body: JSON.stringify(newBlog),
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    //setBlogs([...blogs, newBlog]);
    setPostCount(postCount + 1); //call my post count that fecths my data automatic 
    console.log("blog", data);
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Blog App!</h1>
     <Router>
       <Blogs path="/" blogs={blog} addBlog={addBlog}>{blog.id}</Blogs>
       <Blog path="/blogs/:id" getBlog={getBlog}></Blog>
     </Router>
    
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is my **addBlog.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function AddBlog(props) {
    //state const for hver properties i din object(question)
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [date, setDate] = useState("");

  

    return (
        <><label>Title: </label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Write the title of your Blog" size="30" onChange={(event) => {
                setTitle(event.target.value)
            }
            } /><br /><label>Description: </label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Write the description..." size="30" onChange={(event) => {
                setDescription(event.target.value)
            }} />
           
            <br />
            <button onClick={(event) => props.addBlog(title, description, date)}>Add Question</button>
  

        </>
    );

}

export default AddBlog;
```

I hope someone is able to help me out.

UPDATE here's my screendump of my console - when I press add blog it says POST  401 unAuthrorized.

SORRY IT WAS THE WRONG PROJECT I POSTED AN IMAGE BUT NOW IT'S THE RIGHT PROJECT

[Screendump of my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQSFQ.png)

Comment: Are you sure your blogPost is getting saved? At glance this code seems to be fine. You should try to call your endpoint that gets the post, outside your react application to check if it's returning the new post

Comment: Can you check if there is any error in browser console/ network tab? It mamy be CORS issue

Comment: @AndrzejT I have added a screendump

Comment: @MaCadiz I have tried to call it outside the react (i believe) and it works

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your logs, I think you need to send authorization headers alongside your fetch request in order for the back-end to respond.

You could add the authorization header like that - however, you need to find out/generate authorization token that your backend can accept. Also a little improvement, I would make the function a bit more dynamic by allowing it to accept an URL.

```js
   useEffect(() => {
    async function getData(url) {
      const response = await fetch(URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': <your auth token>
        }
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      setBlogs(data);
    }
    getData(`${API_URL}/blogs`);
  }, [postCount]);
```